# Переворот страницы

Tags: ios, objective-c, время, index, page

Я использую шаблон `Page-Based Application(RootViewController, DataViewController, ModelController)` в Xcode. Я хочу автоматически переворачивать страницу после определенного времени. Как можно это сделать?

Код в `ModelController` для переворота страницы вперед/назад

```
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    NSUInteger index = [self indexOfViewController:(DataViewController *)viewController];
    if ((index == 0) || (index == NSNotFound)) {
        return nil;
    }

    index--;
    return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index storyboard:viewController.storyboard];
}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    NSUInteger index = [self indexOfViewController:(DataViewController *)viewController];
    if (index == NSNotFound) {
        return nil;
    }

    index++;
    if (index == [self.pageData count]) {
        return nil;
    }
    return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index storyboard:viewController.storyboard];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Для того чтобы переворачивать автоматически после определенного времени, подойдет таймер:

```
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:5 
                                         target:self 
                                       selector:@selector(nextPage:) 
                                       userInfo:nil 
                                        repeats:YES];
[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
```

а сам метод переворачивания выглядит так:

```
- (void)nextPage:(id)sender {

    DataViewController *currentViewController = self.pageViewController.viewControllers[0];

    NSUInteger indexOfCurrentViewController = [self.modelController indexOfViewController:currentViewController] + 1;

    if (indexOfCurrentViewController < self.modelController.pageData.count) {
        DataViewController *nextViewController = [self.modelController viewControllerAtIndex:indexOfCurrentViewController storyboard:self.storyboard];

        NSArray *viewControllers = nil;

        viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:nextViewController, nil];

        [self.pageViewController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:YES completion:NULL];
    }
}
```

Заметьте, индекс следующей страницы (контроллера) не должен выходить за пределы массива. И код работает только для iphone. Для ipad Вы можете подобным образом написать проверку, но с 2мя контроллерами. т.е массив `viewControllers` должен содержать два контроллера.

п.с Свойство `pageData` вынесено в хедер класса `ModelController` для видимости. Но Вы можете реализовать логику и в этом классе.