# Переворот страницы по нажатии на кнопку

Tags: ios, objective-c, page

Использую этот код чтобы переворачивать страницу. всего 15 страниц

```
-(IBAction) next:(id)sender {

    NSUInteger page1 = 1;
    NSUInteger page2 = 4;

    DataViewController *firstViewController = [self.modelController viewControllerAtIndex:page1 storyboard:self.storyboard];
    DataViewController *secondViewController = [self.modelController viewControllerAtIndex:page2 storyboard:self.storyboard];

    NSArray *viewControllers = nil;

    viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:firstViewController, secondViewController, nil];

    [self.pageViewController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:YES completion:NULL];

}
```

Проблема в том что я могу выбрать только 2 страницы ( из 15 могу переворачивать 1 и 4)

`NSUInteger page1 = 1;`

`NSUInteger page2 = 4;`

Как мне переворачивать все страницы от 1 - 15?

**UPD**

Ваш код работает. Но когда страницы заканчиваются приложение вылетает. Я использую этот код в `RootViewController` т.к. кнопку с действием могу создать только в нем, а массив с данными находится в `ModelController` где я не могу создать кнопку с действием. Как мне остановить перелистывание, когда страницы заканчиваются?

```
- (void)nextPage:(id)sender {

    DataViewController *ViewController1 = self.pageViewController.viewControllers[0];
    DataViewController *ViewController2 = self.pageViewController.viewControllers[1];

    NSUInteger ViewControllerIndex1 = [self.modelController indexOfViewController:ViewController1] + 2;
    NSUInteger ViewControllerIndex2 = [self.modelController indexOfViewController:ViewController2] + 2;


    DataViewController *firstViewController1 = [self.modelController viewControllerAtIndex:ViewControllerIndex1 storyboard:self.storyboard];
    DataViewController *secondViewController1 = [self.modelController viewControllerAtIndex:ViewControllerIndex1 storyboard:self.storyboard];

    NSArray *viewControllers = nil;

    viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:firstViewController1, secondViewController1, nil];

    [self.pageViewController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:YES completion:NULL];

}
```

Comment: думаю вам подойдет этот ответ: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/547886/Переворот-страницы/548472#548472

Comment: А что значит `pageData`  в вашем ответе?
`self.modelController.pageData.count`

Comment: Я обновил вопрос. Посмотрите пожалуйста.

Comment: pageData - это массив ваших объектов. т.е количество объектов в этом массиве и определяет количество страниц. При перелистывании вы перемещаетесь по массиву (условно). А вылетает потому что вы выходите за границы массива. Обращение к индексу больше чем элементов массива и вызывает ошибку. Вам нужно в этом методе описать условие хождения по массиву (по страницам). В моем примере условие для одностраничного перелистывания (для iphone). Вам нужно  написать условие для двухстраничного перелистывания

Comment: Как я могу написать это условие, если массив находится в ModelController? А мой код в RootViewController

Comment: Свойство pageData вынесено в хедер класса ModelController для видимости. И в RootViewController можно им пользоваться

Comment: Все работает. Дайте ответ, чтобы я мог его принять.

Comment: Если мне нужно переворачивать каждую страницу через разное время. К какой странице нужно создать свой таймер? Или есть другие способы?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В методе `next` необходимо реализовать логику перелистывания для двух страниц. Т.е есть массив элементов, определяющих количество страниц в `ModelController` его можно вынести в хедер класса для видимости. И в RootViewController можно им пользоваться.
А в классе `RootViewController` написать условие, чтобы не выходить за пределы массива, когда переписываются страницы. 
Для автоматического перелистывания нужно создать таймер в классе `RootViewController`, например в методе `viewDidLoad`.

```
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:5 
                                         target:self 
                                       selector:@selector(nextPage:) 
                                       userInfo:nil 
                                        repeats:YES];
[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
```